# How can I check if merging 2 adjacent duplicated characters in a word can produce a specific word?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

I'd like to check if word2 can be produced from word1 if I merge 2 adjacent duplicated characters in word1.

For example:

```
word1 = 'peete'
word2 = 'pete' //OK, because merging ee into e in word1 produces word2

word1 = 'peetee'
word2 = 'peete'

word1 = 'meet'
word2 = 'met'
```

I have this so far but it fails with some inputs:

```js
let checkMerge = (word1, word2) => {
  let charArr = word1.split('');
  let resultArr = [];
  let needToMerge = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < charArr.length; ++i) {
    if (charArr[i] == charArr[i + 1]) continue
    resultArr.push(charArr[i]);
  }
  let resultWord = resultArr.join('');
  if (resultWord == word2) {
    console.log(`JOIN ${needToMerge}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`something's wrong`)
  }
}

checkMerge('peete', 'pete'); //correct
checkMerge('peetee', 'peete'); //fails
checkMerge('meet', 'met'); //correct
```

I also have to get the character which I need to merge (`let needToMerge = '';`) but I can't get it right. So the final output should be like this: `'JOIN char'` What should I do differently? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

some more clarification: 
`function checkMerge` takes two words, `word1` and `word2`. I have to check whether `word2` can be obtained from `word1` by at most one merge. `word2` can't be modified, only `word1` by one merge. 
The function should return `"JOIN c"` if `word2` can be produced from `word1`, by merging two adjacent characters in `word1` (exactly one merge is performed).

For example: 
given `word1 = 'peetee'` and `word2 = 'peete'`, the function should return '`JOIN e`', since if we merge the last two characters (ee) of `word1`, we get 'peete' which is equal to `word2`.

given `word1 = 'peetee'` and `word2 = 'petee'`, the function should return '`JOIN e`', since if we merge the first duplicated characters (ee) of `word1`, we get 'petee' which is equal to `word2`.

Comment: well, you never update `needToMerge`, which I guess would be `charArr[i]` when the `if` condition in your `for` loop evaluates as true?

Comment: Yes I tried needToMerge = charArr[i] but sometimes it wrote wrong character.

Comment: In case you're interested, here's a cleaned up version: https://pastebin.com/nCyEq49D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the characters by using an offset for the other string.

```js
const
    checkMerge = (string1, string2) => [...string1]
         .filter((i => (c, j) => c !== string2[i + j] && --i)(0))

console.log(checkMerge('peete', 'pete'));      // e
console.log(checkMerge('peetee', 'peete'));    // e
console.log(checkMerge('peeteerr', 'peeter')); // er
console.log(checkMerge('meet', 'met'));        // e
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I can't modify word2, only word1 can be modified with one single merge. Could you please update your solution based on this? Thanks!

Comment: i have no idea, what you want. do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: Yes, I edited my original post with some clarification and more examples. Thank you!

Comment: `checkMerge('peeteerr', 'peeter');` should not work, because we have to make two merges on `word1` (ee and rr) to get `word2`. Only one merge is allowed on `word1`.

Comment: you could check the array length and return an error, or whatever fits.

Comment: Ah yes it make sence because the difference between word1 and word2 has to be 1. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**You can replace repeated char with one char and than match.**

```js
let checkMerge = (word1, word2) => {
  word1 = word1.replace(/([a-z])\1+/g,"$1")
  word2 = word2.replace(/([a-z])\1+/g,"$1")
  return word1.indexOf(word2) !== -1
}

console.log(checkMerge('peete', 'pete')); //correct
console.log(checkMerge('peetee', 'peete')); //correct
console.log(checkMerge('meet', 'met')); //correc
console.log(checkMerge('meete', 'meta'));    // false

let checkMerge2 = (word1, word2) => {
  word1 = word1.replace(/([a-z])\1+/g,"$1")
  return word1.indexOf(word2) !== -1
}

console.log(checkMerge2('peete', 'pete')); //correct
console.log(checkMerge2('peetee', 'peete')); //fail
console.log(checkMerge2('meet', 'met')); //correc
console.log(checkMerge2('meete', 'meta'));    // false
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it fails with 'peetee' and 'peete'. However it should work, because if the function merges only the two ee in the end of word1 = peetee the result will be peete which is equal to word2.